# How to set full-window background image using React styling

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to do something very basic in React, but I am having trouble. I want to set a image to be the full-window background of my website.

With CSS styling, I managed to get the image to appear. But I was having trouble setting the image to be a full-window background. So I tried my hand at React styling.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import code from "./code.jpg";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bgImage: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "stretch",
      resizeMode: "stretch"
    }
  });
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Image
        source={require("image!background")}
        style={styles.bgImage}
        alt="background"
      >
        pizza
      </Image>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm pretty new to React. Thanks to anybody who can help me understand what is happening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <Image
    source={require("image!background")}
    style={styles.bgImage}
     width="100%"
    alt="background"
  >
```

Edit:

yes this is true, you in fact do not have `<Image />` defined, where is it coming from?

Did you mean to use the html `<img />` element. All uppercase elements are react specific and cant be globally registered so you have to import that `<Image />` component here, wherever it is defined in your app.

The second error is also valid. what is it you are trying to do with the syntax 
"image!background"

This is not valid syntax as far as I know. the " ! " usually denotes a "is not" in a conditional. such as

```
2 !== 3
```

or

```
2 is not equal to 3
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get: 'Image' is not defined and Unexpected '!' in 'image!background'.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment, check it out and let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I tried to find a React <Image /> component to import into my file, but I couldn't find anything. Also, I honestly just found the "image!background" syntax online.

Comment: What is the <Image /> component then?

Comment: I don't know, it was recommended in many tutorials I saw. I thought it would work but it has been giving me that issue :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `CSS`

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bgImage: {
      backgroundRepeat:'no-repeat',
      backgroundSize:'cover',
      height:'100%',
      backgroundPosition:'bottom' 
    }
  });
```